# Insert a logo next to any DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Firefox extension which amends the contents of a loaded webpage. First I select all the elements of which the "src" or "href" attributes match my regex (this part of the code works).

Then, I would like to place a little image at the top right corner of the found element's parent using the following code:

```
    /* create and add attributes to image */
var img = window.content.document.createElement("img");
var b = window.content.document.createAttribute("src");
b.nodeValue = "chrome://plugin/content/agent.png";
img.setAttributeNode(b);
img.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("ds"); });
img.style.display = "block";
img.style.border = "3px solid red";
img.style.position = "relative";
img.style.top = "-10px";
img.style.right = "-10px";
img.style.left = "20px";
```

// ... the code to return the element...

```
//now insert the image
$jq(img).appendTo(element.parentNode);
```

The current result is that either the image is shown just at the  bottom of the element's parent or not shown at all.

If you look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/yzwh5/64/ - I would like my button to work in a similar manner to that red cross.

Answer (score 1):

You must "play" with the element's CSS positioning, in fact it doesn't matter where do you insert the images, but where you do position them.

Maybe you would like to take a look at "next-to", a jQuery plugin that automates the calculations to position an element next to another element

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.PlaceThisDiv').nextTo($('.ThisOtherDiv'), {position:'right', shareBorder:'top'});
</script>
```

As you can see in this Fiddle i have prepared (contains the plugin itself)

http://jsfiddle.net/PvcNr/

you will get you something like this:

[image: See screenshot]

More info: https://code.google.com/p/next-to/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS code like this:

```
.my-ext-overlay:after {
    content:url(smiley.gif);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -16px; margin-top: -16px;
}
```

and then adding the ".my-ext-overlay" class name to each element you find.

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/x2Fvn/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, CSS floats are called `cssFloat` (or `htmlFloat` in some browsers) because `float` is a reserved word. Second, there is no such `float` value as `block`.

Third, you missed an `x` in `-10px` for the `right` property.

Fourth, setting both relative left and right positions can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Fifth, you shouldn't use `createAttribute`, since attribute nodes aren't reliable in all browsers. Instead, use `setAttribute` on the element.

Sixth, if this did work it would mess up page layout around the element you're searching for, so you would be better off with `position: absolute` so it doesn't affect the flow. If you do this, however, you should use `margin-left` instead of `left` (same for other directions), to shift the element around.

I think that should at least get the thing close to working...

Comment: That's one of so many solutions I used. I amended it how you suggested but still no joy. Any other suggestions/solutions how to go around this problem?